# Can I assign the value directly to LocalDateTime?

Tags: java

I know that I can assign the value this way :

```
LocalDateTime session = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.FEBRUARY, 12, 10, 30);
```

But is there a way to assign value directly :

```
LocalDateTime session = LocalDateTime.of(2019-12-15_15:14:21.629);
```

or maybe :

```
LocalDateTime session = LocalDateTime.of(2019-12-15T15:14:21.629);
```

?

Comment: You can use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-. The javadoc is your friend. Consult it. You'll learn a lot as a bonus.

Comment: NO, neither `2019-12-15_15:14:21.629` nor `2019-12-15T15:14:21.629` are  valid tokens in Java; there are no such literals in Java, for dates: [3.10. Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10) (actually `2019-12-15_15` represents an `int`, but of no help here)

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way below using `DateTimeFormatter` :

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
LocalDateTime session = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-12-15T15:14:21.629", formatter);
```

or

You can directly parse the string in the `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime session = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-12-15T15:14:21.629");
```

Comment: Your pattern is the ISO pattern, which exists as a constant, but which is used by default by LocalDateTime.parse() (without argument) anyway.

Comment: @JBNizet I thought for variant time string. So, I gave it. But I have updated my answer as it is the default.

Answer (score 1):

Your latter version comes closer:

```
    LocalDateTime session = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-12-15T15:14:21.629");
    System.out.println("session: " + session);
```

Output is:

> session: 2019-12-15T15:14:21.629

`LocalDateTIme` and the other classes of java.time not only print ISO 8601 format from their `toString` methods. They also parse the same format as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter. Your string with the `T` between date and time, `2019-12-15T15:14:21.629` is in ISO 8601 format, the international standard. Only you need to put double quotes before and after to tell Java that it is a string.

If you wanted to use the variant with an underscore (`_`)  between date and time, you would still need to wrap it in quotes to form a string and additionally define a formatter for parsing it as shown in the answer by Anish B.

### Links

- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Documentation of the 1-arg `LocalDateTime.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence))